# Terminating a c program when the user enters a blank line

Tags: c, input

Hi i am writing a program to count the number of lines the user enters, i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int readline(char line[], int max);

/* count lines in input */
main() {
int c, nl,max, i;
max = 99;
char line[100];
nl = 0;


while (( readline(line, max) != 0)){
    ++nl;

  }
  printf("%d\n", nl);
}

/* readline: read a line from standard input, return its length or 0
 */
int readline(char line[], int max)
{
  if (fgets(line, max, stdin) == NULL)
    return 0;
  else
    return strlen(line);
}
```

but i am not sure how to terminate the program and have "nl" printed to the screen, i am using the cygwin64 terminal to write and execute the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t n;
while(fgets(line,max,stdin))
{
   n = strlen(line);
   if( n == 1 && line[n-1] == '\n')
   {
     //This is a empty line 
   }
}
```

Basically `fgets()` comes with a newline character and you can use this to confirm whether there was any input in the line or just a newline character was entered.

> readline returns the text of the line read.  A blank line  returns 
>   the
>          empty string.  If EOF is encountered while reading a line, and the line
>          is empty, NULL is returned.  If an EOF is read with a  non-empty    line,
>          it is treated as a newline.

So you can check for empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition into like this,

```
while (( readline(line, max)  <= 1)){
  ...
}
```

When you enter the empty new line then that new line will be placed in that array.
So it gives the `strlen` as `1`.